Get manipulated image (BE) in fluid template
Is there a way to get the image, an editor manipulates via BE (Image manipulation -> Open Editor -> i .e crop or set to 16:9... in TYPO3 12 with an content blocks (https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/content_blocks) Element?
Basic code:
...
<f:for each="{data.slider_item}" as="slider_item" iteration="i">
    <div class="carousel-item {f:if(condition: i.isFirst, then: 'active')}" data-bs-interval="10000">
        <f:for each="{slider_item.image}" as="slider_item_image" iteration="i">
            <f:image image="{slider_item_image.originalFile}" loading="lazy" class="d-block w-66 h-auto"/>
        </f:for>
    </div>          
</f:for>
...                        
                                

When croping/resizing an image in the backend, still the original image is delivered. I have understood that slider_item_image.originalFile always outputs the orignalfile, right? But how can I access the reference?
There´s an older post with the same topic for fluid (without content blocks), but no solution.. How to get cropped image dimensions in a Fluid template in Typo3 v8
Thanks!
Output of the image, that the editor created / croped / ...

Might be a stupid question, but should using image="{slider_item_image}" already utilize the cropped file reference metadata and deliver the cropped image?!

If the reference (in which the editor edits the image) is passed to the VH, the cropping should be applied automatically. If one passes originalFile, one would have to use the cropping independently.

Thanks @JulianHofmann for the explanation. I´ll need to dig deeper, because I use a content block element with an normal image field. If I find a way, I come back here.

Maybe you could update your post and show us more of your code for understanding, what you are doing or want to achieve. Normally, there's no need to care about cropping. Therefore, the question is what you do that it cannot be applied automatically.

I´ve update the post, didn´t found a solution so far

I havent worked with content blocks so far, but this is how the cropped image can be accessed:
You propably need a FileProcessor in your Project
image of FileProcessor
To access the cropped version of your Image you have to look up the path in that specific field you stored it in the Backend.
Eg. if you used an TextMedia Element for your image, the field (the one in red brackets behind the Label) is assets.
So in your template you have to use the assets field. Inside the propertiesOfFileReference you will find the name of your cropVariant which we need for fluid (use a debug _all to see what fields you have).
Use the f:uri.image tag to access the crop variant you've looked up previously.
It sholud look something like this:
<f:uri.image image="{assets.0}" absolute="1" cropVariant="mobile"></f:uri.image>

So mobile in this case is the name of the cropVariant.
I guess it also works with the f:image tag, it depends on what you need
Location of cropVariants
